# How to get values from excel without change in their cell format type?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am using Excel interop library to get values from Excel files using c#.net.

Now I am facing an issue that all the values are getting in General or text format I think.

I have used the below piece of code.

```
        string fileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\123.xlsx";
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlApp.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1];
        Excel.Range excelCell = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        Object[,] values = (Object[,])excelCell.Value;
```

Example:
       [image]

```
I am getting '41369' instead of 4/5/2013 from B4 cell and 100 instead of 100.00 from A2 call.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code,

```
CellVal = objWorkbook.WorkSheets(1).Cells(6, 1).Value
MsgBox CellVal
```

This will return the correct date format.

Comment: Please type this code on the next line and not on the same
MsgBox CellVal

Comment: The **Value** property gives DateTime format.If data is 4/13/2013 it gives as 4/13/2013 12:00:00 AM.

Comment: You can then remove the time element from the same mask

Answer (score 0):

The number for the date you get is the number of days from Jan 1, 1900.

For your date you ll use

```
int NumberOfDaysAfter19000101 = 41369;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddDays(NumberOfDaysAfter19000101 - 2);
```

I answered in this thread for why you subtract 2 from the NumberOfDaysAfter19000101 .
[Access and SQL Server calculate date differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422237/access-and-sql-server-calculate-date-differently/16422929#16422929)

Comment: Thank you for this info. But i need to know is there any way to get all data as in the Excel without specifying the each row or column format.